# Printing a Vector that was passed to a print function

Tags: c++, function, vector

[This is the code that I have written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftIBu.png)

I am getting an error when trying to print out the vector values and I can not figure out why.
I passed the array to the function `print(&v1)`.
Can someone help me figure out why this error is occurring and if there is a better alternative way to print out the vector elements in my function.

Comment: Please include both the code and the error as text in the question. Also please read about [mcve]

Comment: You have some misunderstanding about **pointers** and **references**. I think this is not a good place to try and teach that, you should probably pick up a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1171191), or ask your teacher to explain those concepts again.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is to change `v[x]` to `(*v)[x]` in `print`, but I don't think that will really help your understanding much. (And it is one fix, but probably not the best fix).

Comment: `print1` seems to be correct. Why do you want to use a pointer in `print`? You need pointers a lot less often than some teachers are trying to make you believe.

Comment: @user463035818 sorry first time asking a question on stack overflow, quickly had to get the question out

Comment: `vector<int> *v` -> `vector<int> & v`

Comment: @D.Mensah is copy pasting text really more difficult than copy pasting a screen shot?

Comment: "quickly had to get the question out " sorry but thats the wrong approach. You should have read the [help] and take the [tour] before asking the question. This would save you some downvotes ;)

Comment: @user463035818 the outline of the lab that I am working on right now requires that we use a pointer in print

Comment: @D.Mensah I you really want a pointer in `print`, the 3rd comment  is the answer.

Comment: then thats a stupid  unrealistic requirement and they should have told you before the assignment how to work with pointers, otherwise I dont get the point of the exercise, aka you need to review your lecture notes ;). Dont get me wrong, but SO cannot replace classes, direct teaching or reading books

Comment: This is one of those problems where the issue is the _level of indirection_. Your compiler error is telling you that you're trying to print an entire vector, when you want to print a single member. That's because the parameter to the function is a pointer, rather than a reference. I understand that your instructor wants you to pass a pointer (perhaps to press home the lesson that they're really not the best solution, quite often) but the best fix might be, as BoBTFish suggested, simply dereference the pointer to get back to the vector, before using the array index to get the actual value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You correctly used `->` in `print1` instead of `.` (like in `print`) to operate on the *pointer* to the vector. This works because `x->y` is equivalent to `(*x).y`, meaning you correctly dereferenced the pointer to the vector before accessing it.

Except for `[]`. Here you also have to dereference the pointer before using `[]`. So:

```
cout << (*v)[x] << endl;
```

There is no abbreviation (also called "syntactic sugar") for `(*x)[]` like there is for `(*x).y`, so you must do it manually.

---

The error message is confusing because using `[]` on a *pointer* is valid - `x[y]` is equivalent to `*(x+y)`, which means you are doing pointer arithmetics: You use `v` as if it was a (C-style) array of vectors, and you try to get the `x`th element from this array of vectors. Lucky for you, the compiler doesn't know how to `<<` a `Vector` with `cout` - but if it could, the code would compile and do something you (probably) did not intend.